# Rails 7 Update Breaking in Production on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, airbrake, ruby-on-rails-7

First post here, so bear with me...

I recently updated my Rails app to 7.0.1 (latest stable release) from 6.1.4. My test suite is still green and the deployment to Heroku succeeds. However, when trying to open the app I get the classic "We're sorry, but something went wrong message". Checking the logs, this is the output:

[ErrorMessage1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhLfe.png)
[ErrorMessage2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fYhg.png)

I'm still relatively new to Rails/Heroku deployments, and I'm stumped on where to look to try and fix this. The NoMethodError does not show many solutions online, any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is related to this [issue](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/issues/1177)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: fixed the rails version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is related to an open issue about airbrake [Discussion on rails repo](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43006#discussion_r783840849) [Discussion on airbrake repo](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/issues/1177#issuecomment-998138809).
The issue is triggered when we use eager loading. For now, the quickest solution would be to disable eager loading and watch the issue or continue with rails 6 or temporarily stop using airbrake.

```
config.eager_load = false // to disable eager loading _ production.rb
```

***[edit]***
A new version of `airbrake` fixes this issue so that you won't need to disable eager loading in production. [airbrake:13.0.0 fix](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/pull/1211).

So, you'll just need to update to the proper version in your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Disabling eager loading worked, the app loads again.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I released airbrake v13.0.0, which includes the fix for the issue. @brinxi11

Comment: Great @brinxi11! I'll update the answer accordingly

Comment: This fixed my staging/production environments as well.